# Sitecore Xpress login failing

Tags: sitecore

I am new to SiteCore and I have instaled the free edition of Sitecore express on my machine

with that I am able to see the sitemap
but when I click on Edit Site it is taking me to a login page where the credentials which I gave during download are not working

can anyone help me in this regard

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sent to `/sitecore/login`? The typical credentials are, username "admin" and password "b" -- they may be different for Xpress though.

Answer (score 1):

In your site's Right side you will find a 'Who am I' heading under that there have some predefined users which can be used to login.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I reinstalled and used the MS express DB as the configuration (requires you have installed MS sql DB). I renamed some tables, check the DB connection string and such and and I could login.

I used the standard name password login: admin b